# Same app, different style for different SDK

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm new to android. As part of an ActionBar exercise I'm trying to use different theme for different API level. This is an simple app with a blank activity.

Details about the app :
Min SDK version : 17 / 4.2 JB

My AndroidManifest entry :

```
<manifest package="bitsandpizzas.test.com.bitzpizzaz"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OrderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_order"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity code :

```
package bitsandpizzas.test.com.bitzpizzaz;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ShareActionProvider _shareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void share (Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        this._shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        setIntent("Sample Text ....");
    }

    private void setIntent (String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        this._shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        //share(menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_create_order:
                Intent orderIntent = new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(orderIntent);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_setting:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a default style.xml and a style.xml for v21
Default style.xml entry :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#AE71AB</item>
</style>
```

style.xml for v21 :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

When I ran this on Nexus 4 simulator API-19 I get the below screen :

[image: notice no action bar]

When I run the same on Nexus 5 simulator API-21 I get the below screen :

[image]

To fix the API-19 issue I need to have MainActivity extend import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Then on API-19 / Nexus 4 I get the UI as expected :

[image]

But on API-21 it crashes.

Also I noticed with MainActivity extending Activity on v21 the action I added (share and order, the plus sign) never comes on the Action Bar, despite having enough space.

Question :
1. What is the mistake, how do I effectively handle different style for different API level effectively ?
2. Why the defined actions never appear on ActionBar for API-21 ?

Thanks in advance for all the guidance.

Comment: could you please add the logcats? (about that crash) and of course, please edit your question with adding the correct `extends`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can use `AppCompat` after this post for all api(s):

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

which means, you are using incorrect theme on your activity, let's take a look at those codes :

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

change it to :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

you could do these things like removing unused codes with Android Studio Shortcuts btw,

Let's use `AppCompat` :)

i'm pretty sure, in the logcat `androidstudio` says, you should change the theme to `AppCompat`

Comment: using style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" in style.xml has resolve it. thanks a lot.

Comment: Yw.let us know if this answer was useful by selecting this answer as the correct and best.Happy programming!